# How to ask user for username or other data with vs code extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to receive some input from the user, such as `username` and use it in the code. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To ask for simple input you can use the [`vscode.window.showInputBox()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showInputBox) API.
E.g.:

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode";

const input = await vscode.window.showInputBox();
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(input);
```

For advanced usage there is also the [`vscode.InputBox`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#InputBox) which is created via the [`vscode.window.createInputBox()`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.createInputBox) command